# Нужно вывести хеш с порядковым номером (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, хеширование

Мне нужно вывести ключи (именно ключи) хеша с порядковыми номерами.

Например -
есть хеш `{BMW => 10000, AUDI => 50000, FERRARI => 70000}`

Нужен такой вывод:

```
1. BMW
2. AUDI
3. FERRARI
```

Я пробовал такой код:

```
hash.each_with_index {|x, i| puts "#{i+1}. #{x}"
```

Но он выводит и ключ, и значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
hash.keys.each_with_index {|key, i| puts "#{i+1}. #{key}"}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // например, изложите словами, в чём именно состоит ваше предложение.

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = { BMW: 10000, AUDI: 50000, FERRARI: 70000 }

hash.each_with_index {|(key, value), i| puts "#{i+1}. #{key}"}

1. BMW
2. AUDI
3. FERRARI
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]